# How to reproduce UserRecoverableAuthIOException on Android device?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

When I debug with Google Drive API, I met this problem:

First time when I call `service.about().get().execute();` in my app, it will catch `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` and my code call startActivity.

But after I confirm the `auth dialog` , it never show up again.

I want to debug the whole auth routine, but how to erase auth data and let it raise the exception again?

Comment: I tried to clear data of Google Play Service, Google Play Store, but not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just unconnect the app from where the Google service you use, such as the "Manage apps" setting in Google Drive webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens to revoke access of the app and expect the exception again.